# npm error npm ERR! code ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for express@undefined4.16.3

Tags: nodes, npm-install, node-modules

whenever run npm commands like npm install and npm update. I'm getting following error.

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for express@undefined4.16.3
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'Mac-Book'
npm ERR! notarget

I have tried reinstalling node through brew, but getting same error.

Comment: are you in the project root dir, where package.json resides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have config file before npm install. It should fix this problem. After that enter this commands:

```html
npm install

npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for "npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ...", as in my case, is that I use npm mirror, `registry=https://registry.npmmirror.com` while the mirror has not sync with `registry=https://registry.npmjs.com`